# Installing Toolchain

Tags: configure

I'm trying to install a toolchain in Ubuntu 18.04 to compile a custom firmware for my router. The README states to run `./configure` but when I do so it comes back with: `configure: error: cannot find install-sh, install.sh, or shtool in config "."/config`.

This is for an Asus DSL-AC88U for which I downloaded the source code from http://www.asus.com/uk/Networking/DSL-AC88U/HelpDesk_Download/ which contains the source code for router and toolchain.

After `autoreconf -i` the `./configure` now runs, but I run `make` and get:

```
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/katana/Downloads/GPL_DSL_AC88U_v11006_build591/crosstools-arm-gcc-4.6-linux-3.4-uclibc-0.9.32-binutils-2.21-NPTL.Rel1.2' 
CC loaders/dlopen.lo ./libtool: ./libtool: Is a directory Makefile:694: recipe for target 'loaders/dlopen.lo' failed make[1]: ***   
[loaders/dlopen.lo] Error 126 make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/katana/Downloads/GPL_DSL_AC88U_v11006_build591/crosstools-arm-gcc-4.6-linux-3.4-uclibc-0.9.32-binutils-2.21-NPTL.Rel1.2' 
Makefile:502: recipe for target 'all' failed 
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Comment: Do you have GCC installed? Are you using an Acqua or RoadRunner board?

Comment: Hi Mitch i have gcc installed,im not using either an Acqua or RoadRunner board,this is for An Asus DSL-AC88U for which i downloaded the the source code from [link]://www.asus.com/uk/Networking/DSL-AC88U/HelpDesk_Download/ which contains the source code for router and toolchain..

Comment: try running `autoreconf -i`

Comment: ok tried autoreconf -i

Comment: ./configure now runs but i run make i get 
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/katana/Downloads/GPL_DSL_AC88U_v11006_build591/crosstools-arm-gcc-4.6-linux-3.4-uclibc-0.9.32-binutils-2.21-NPTL.Rel1.2'
  CC       loaders/dlopen.lo
./libtool: ./libtool: Is a directory
Makefile:694: recipe for target 'loaders/dlopen.lo' failed
make[1]: *** [loaders/dlopen.lo] Error 126
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/katana/Downloads/GPL_DSL_AC88U_v11006_build591/crosstools-arm-gcc-4.6-linux-3.4-uclibc-0.9.32-binutils-2.21-NPTL.Rel1.2'
Makefile:502: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2

Comment: Hi Norbert unfortunately my Router is Unsupported by dd-wrt....

Comment: i Have its unsuppurted.. the dsl-ac88u is based on a custom version of openwrt

Comment: Oh, I see, the RT-AC88U is supported, but DSL is not. I'm currently writing comprehensive answer for you.

Answer (score 1):

You need install build tools at first:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential git ncurses-dev subversion zlib1g-dev m4 automake autoconf
```

And do not extract their toolchain to `/opt` at all. It will not work. It requires newer version of `m4` and some other stuff.
The firmware is based on OpenWRT, so it can compile toolchain on its own.

Then extract the `DSL-AC88U_FW_V1_10_06_Build591_GPL_official.tar.bz2` archive and go to firmware directory

```
cd ~/Downloads/GPL_DSL_AC88U_v11006_build591/DSL-AC88U_FW_V1_10_06_Build591_GPL_official

# download package with broken link
wget http://lmde-mirror.gwendallebihan.net/latest/pool/main/m/mklibs/mklibs_0.1.34.tar.gz -O dl/mklibs_0.1.34.tar.gz
```

and compile both the firmware and the toolchain with

```
make V=s
```

---

Notes:

1. the compilation on my 18.04.2 LTS machine failed, I did not get any factory/sysupgrade images.
2. extracting the toolchain to `/opt` does not help:

   ```
   cd /
   sudo tar -xf ~/Downloads/GPL_DSL_AC88U_v11006_build591/DSL-AC88U_FW_V1_10_06_Build591_GPL_official/crosstools-arm-gcc-4.6-linux-3.4-uclibc-0.9.32-binutils-2.21-NPTL.Rel1.2.tar.bz2
   ```

   and ends with

   > autom4te: need GNU m4 1.4 or later: /opt/toolchains/crosstools-arm-gcc-4.6-linux-3.4-uclibc-0.9.32-binutils-2.21-NPTL/usr/bin/m4
   >   aclocal-1.11: autom4te failed with exit status: 1
   >   Makefile:950: recipe for target 'aclocal.m4' failed

Comment: ok now i have about 5 errors towards the end of the compile 1st is : 1/DSL-AC88U_FW_V1_10_06_Build591_GPL_official/toolchain/wrapper'
Testing external toolchain for ipv6 support ... Toolchain directory '/opt/toolchains/crosstools-arm-gcc-4.6-linux-3.4-uclibc-0.9.32-binutils-2.21-NPTL' does not exist.
failed

Comment: Then the problem is a bit harder. And you should start to learn [OpenWRT BuildRoot documentation](https://openwrt.org/docs/start) to get it compiled. I can not help with it.

Comment: Ok `ill have a look thank you for your help...